# How to find out all variations used by Fuzzy query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch6.8 for a fuzzy query. I understand fuzzy query uses distance-based measure to find all terms for querying. (`An edit distance is the number of one-character changes needed to turn one term into another.`). 
I wonder how I can get all terms used by a fuzzy query for my document?
For example, below is one of my query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "user": {
                "value": "ki"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I know what the variations used to find matched document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with fuzzy searches in particular, it is vital to understand that in elasticsearch text is first run through an analyzer before being made available for search. When data is indexed it is processed into what are known as 'terms', the actual searchable units in the database. It is the analyzed terms (what terms are is covered in Elasticsearch from the Bottom Up), not the actual stored documents that are searched.

more here :
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search